# delete text without element inside div after some button

Tags: jquery

here the code

```
<div
    id="user-alert"
    class="alert alert-danger col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 alert-dismissible"
    role="alert"
>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert" aria-hidden="true">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    myquestion is,, how to remove/delete this text using jquery, just this text only,,
</div>
```

i've tried `$('#user-alert :not(:first-child)').remove();` but it won't work

i also tried `$('#user-alert button.close).text('')` still not work

Comment: maybe `$($('#user-alert')[0].childNodes).last().remove();`

Comment: See My Answer -> It should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this
**UPDATED**

```
$( "#YourIdHere" ).contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

Selector for the last node of element is `$('#user-alert').contents().last()[0]` and using that selector you can remove the text of it.

```
$('#user-alert').contents().last()[0].textContent='';
```

**Working snippet:**

```js
$('#user-alert').contents().last()[0].textContent='';
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div
     id="user-alert"
     class="alert alert-danger col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 alert-dismissible"
     role="alert"
     >
  <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert" aria-hidden="true">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
  </button>
  myquestion is,, how to remove/delete this text using jquery, just this text only,,
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, try putting your text in a span. For example:

```
<div
id="user-alert"
class="alert alert-danger col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 alert-dismissible"
role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert" aria-hidden="true">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    <span id="myText">myquestion is,, how to remove/delete this text using jquery, just this text only,,</span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#myText').remove();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep a reference to the button and add it back to the div after the html is cleared.

```
var myDiv = jQuery('#user-alert');
var myButton = jQuery('button');
myButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    myDiv.html('');
    myButton.appendTo(myDiv);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will helps you

```
<div
    id="user-alert"
    class="alert alert-danger col-md-offset-1 col-md-10 alert-dismissible"
    role="alert"
>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-hide="alert" aria-hidden="true">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
    myquestion is,, how to remove/delete this text using jquery, just this text only,,
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
$('.close').on('click',function(){

$(this).closest('div').remove();
})
})
</script>
```

you can use either `closest()` or `parents()`